# How do I fix "Malformed entry 49 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)"

Tags: backup

I have read several previous posts. But am unable to see what is wrong with my line 49 in the sources list.
My line 49 reads "deb http://archive.canonical.com/bionic artner"

Answer (score 2):

Please add a "p" before "artner" to make it "partner".

Comment: Thanks. I see the issue and used a text editor to change both line 49 and 50 by adding the p to partner. I saved the edited sources.list file. I also saved the original as sources2.list. Now how do I update the original sources.list file with the updated copy. I tried sudo apt-get update. But that failed. I think because there was no name of a file to update and a location for the new file?